# Como evitar contar dias festivos

Tags: php, sql

Hola tengo una aplicación para que un usuario pueda coger días de vacaciones. Tengo una función que no me cuenta ni fin de semanas ni festivo. Por ejemplo en Andalucia el 29 de Marzo es festivo, si un usuario se coge vacaciones desde el 28 de marzo hasta el 2 de abril, pues le saldrá que se ha cogido 3 días de vacaciones ya que no ha contado ni el festivo ni el fin de semana. Hasta ahí todo bien. Mi problema viene cuando yo selecciono nada más que el día 29 de marzo. Si yo pongo las vacaciones de ese día solamente y elijo 29 de marzo a las 08:00 hasta el 29 de marzo a las 17:00, me cuenta ese día como 1 en vez de contarmelo como 0. Alguna ayuda?? Aqui os dejo mi función:

```
function diashabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin){
    $inicio = strtotime($fechainicio);
    $final = strtotime($fechafin);

    $dias = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fechas as f join calendarios as c on c.PK_CALENDARIOS = f.FK_CALENDARIO join sec_users as u on u.fk_zona = c.PK_CALENDARIOS WHERE u.login = 'user1' AND f.FECHA_ZONA between '".$fechainicio."' AND '".$fechafin."'";
    sc_lookup(rr, $sql);

    while(date('Y-m-d', $inicio) <= date('Y-m-d', $final)){
        $dias += date('N', $inicio) < 6 ? 1 : 0;
        $inicio = strtotime("+1 day", $inicio);
    }

    $dias -= {rr[0][0]};

    return $dias;
}
```

Comment: Has probado con quitar las hh:mm:ss de la fechainicio y fechafin? Es decir, formatear las variables. Colocando fechainicio a las 00:00:00 y fechafin 23:59:59.

Comment: @DMAVE Si, y eso me va perfecto, pero los usuarios pueden elejir horas extra tambien, si por ejemplo usuario1 trabajó o trabaja el día 29 que es festivo, de las 08:00 hasta las 12:00, me dá ese problema también

Comment: @DMAVE El problema es que si tu elijes el día 29 desde las 00:00 si lo cuenta como 0, pero en el momento que lo elijas desde las 01:00 ya lo cuenta como 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes darle un formato fijo al las fechas (fechainicio, fechafin).
A fin de cuentas **no te interesan las horas** ya que el resultado son dias (**diashabiles**). El error te puede dar cuando la fechainicio/fechafin no abarcan el dia que has establecido como dia habil en "fechas.FECHA_ZONA".

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function diashabiles($fechainicio, $fechafin){
    $fechainicio= date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($fechainicio));
    $fechafin= date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($fechafin));
    //-- Acá continúa tu código.
    $inicio = strtotime($fechainicio);
    $final = strtotime($fechafin);

    $dias = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fechas as f join calendarios as c on c.PK_CALENDARIOS = f.FK_CALENDARIO join sec_users as u on u.fk_zona = c.PK_CALENDARIOS WHERE u.login = 'user1' AND f.FECHA_ZONA between '".$fechainicio."' AND '".$fechafin."'";
    sc_lookup(rr, $sql);

    while(date('Y-m-d', $inicio) <= date('Y-m-d', $final)){
        $dias += date('N', $inicio) < 6 ? 1 : 0;
        $inicio = strtotime("+1 day", $inicio);
    }

    $dias -= {rr[0][0]};

    return $dias;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! Me ha sido de gran ayuda!!